Chooice of the family distribution and handle of factor variables in HGAMM (Hierarchical Generalized Additive Mixed Models)
my research question is what covariates are related to higher contacts during the lockdown period. The dataset includes the contact information for each participant for at least two-time points. The contact information is like a contact diary, the participants were asked to write down their contacts during the past 24 hours, including the number of contacts, location of the contacts, relationship, duration, etc. Besides, the participants were also asked to provide their demographic information, such as age, employment status, state, etc. This survey includes three waves, one is before the lockdown but still with some restricted measures, and the other two are during the lockdown.
After watching the YouTube video and paper (Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: an introduction with mgcv) from Pro. Gavin Simpson, I choose HGAMM to build the model.
First, I divided the dataset into train data and test data using whether the participant ID is odd or even.
data_train <- subset(data, token%%2==0 ) # (using even token ID to train the model)
data_test  <- subset(data, token%%2==1) # (using odd token ID to test the model)

Then, I use age as the common smoother and other variables as random effect or group effect to build three models as the paper instructed: G, GS, and GI.
By comparing the summary of the models and using the test data and the models to predict the fit value, then comparing the fit value with the real data, the performance of GI is much better than G or GS. The model I built is as below.
bam(n ~ s(age, k = 10, m = 2) + 
                   s(hh_size, k = 7, m = 2) +
                   employment_2cat + 
                   period * place +
                   s(age, by = interaction(period, place), k = 10, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
                   s(hh_size, by = interaction(period, place), k = 7, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
                   s(token, k = 431, bs="re") + 
                   s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs="re") , 
                 data = data_train, 
                 family = tw(link="log"), method = "fREML", 
                 drop.unused.levels = FALSE) 

At this stage, I am stuck with four questions, and cannot find answers or solve it by myself.
Q1 is about the family distribution choice. I built two models: modGI_4 with family = nb() and modGI_5 with family = tw(link="log"). The summary results are a little different between the two models, the computation time is 28 mins vs 3 mins, and the prediction results show that modGI_5 with family = tw(link="log") seems to be better. But the AIC comparison indicates that modGI_4 is better.
                    df      AIC
data_modGI_4 292.7905 10660.96
data_modGI_5 269.2693 10760.64


So my first question is should I choose the family distribution based on the AIC or the visualization of the comparison between prediction and real value from test data?
Q2, Besides the two continuous covariates, age and household size (hh_size), I also included the employment status, and want to include other factor variables, such as gender, or education level. The model I build is like this:
bam(n ~ s(age, k = 10, m = 2) + 
                   s(hh_size, k = 7, m = 2) +
                   employment_2cat * interaction(period, place) + 
                   period + 
                   place +
                   s(age, by = interaction(period, place), k = 10, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
                   s(hh_size, by = interaction(period, place), k = 7, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
                   s(token, k = 431, bs="re") + 
                   s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs="re") , 
                 data = data_train, 
                 family = tw(link="log"), method = "fREML", 
                 drop.unused.levels = FALSE) 

But the summary result of the model is different and includes several NaN values.
My second question is how to add the categorical or factor covariates properly. That model can return the main effect of this variable but also how this variable is affected by the interaction between period and location.
Q3 is about the interpretation of the result that the token has a significant effect.
Approximate significance of smooth terms:            edf    Ref.df    F   p-value 
s(token)                                         1.658e+02 427.000  0.741 < 2e-16 ***
s(Bundesland)                                    1.392e-04  15.000  0.000 0.78530   

Does it mean that the current information could not answer the research question that personal choice is more decisive for contact behaviour?
Q4 is about the warning message when using test data and models to predict the fit value. The warning message is as below. Is the warning message raised because of the difference in the token, if so, is the fit value predicted based on other covariates?
data_modGI_5_pred <- cbind(data_test, 
predict(data_modGI_5, data_test, se.fit=TRUE, type = "response"))

    Warning message:
    In predict.gam(object, newdata = newdata, type = type, se.fit = se.fit,  :
      factor levels 1003, 1005, 1011, 1035, 1051, 1063, 1131, 1143, 1165, 1187, 1193, 1197, 1199, 1201, 
1237, 1243, 1267, 1281, 1327, 1369, 1385, 1387, 1421, 1437, 1463, 1465, 1591, 
1609, 1615, 1629, 1641, 1665, 1681, 1685, 1699, 1743, 1749, 1801, 1819, 1839, 
1841, 1855, 1861, 1889, 1927, 1951, 1991, 2023, 2063, 2085, 2127, 2129, 2139, 
2145, 2175, 2197, 2229, 2239, 2243, 2249, 2277, 2299, 2307, 2309, 2351, 2353, 
2387, 2389, 2393, 2409, 2435, 2453, 2473, 2477, 2513, 2545, 2567, 2575, 2623, 
2629, 2631, 2647, 2701, 2775, 2785, 2807, 2823, 2917, 2947, 3053, 3071, 3083, 
3089, 3091, 3103, 3189, 3197, 3251, 3267, 3283, 3287, 3289, 3295, 3311, 3325, 
3363, 3393, 3429, 3435, 3437, 3457, 3477, 3501, 3503, 3517, 3527, 3541, 3579, 
3581, 3607, 3609, 3617, 3635, 3683, 3709, 3731, 3735, 3743, 3759, 3785, 3793, 
3829, 3859, 3873, 3907, 3909, 3923, 3965, 3971, 3999, 4001, 4039, 4051, 4063, 
4065, 4075, 4079, 4081, 4103, 4105, 4127, 4141, 4159, 4165, 4193, 4213, 4233, 
4241, 4265, 4293, 4313, 4347, 4359, 4383, 43 [... truncated]

---------- update with results and further questions ------------
Here is the summary of the model. Except the age and household size, four factor variables are added, marital status, employment status, time of contact that happened during the weekend or not, region (east or west Germany), and education levels. Before the model was fit, a pp (interaction between period and place) variable was created, and the full dataset was used for the model.
summary(modGI)    
Family: Negative Binomial(0.651) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
n ~ s(age, k = 10, m = 2) + s(hh_size, k = 7, m = 2) + s(age, 
    by = pp, k = 10, bs = "tp", m = 1) + s(hh_size, by = pp, 
    k = 7, bs = "tp", m = 1) + (employment_2cat + weekend + region + 
    marital_2cat + education_2cat) * pp + s(token, k = 431, bs = "re") + 
    s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
                                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                        1.994e-01  1.147e-01   1.739 0.082031 .  
employment_2catNot Employed                        2.549e-01  1.332e-01   1.913 0.055737 .  
weekendWeekend                                     3.553e-01  1.352e-01   2.629 0.008591 ** 
regionEast Germany                                -2.251e-03  1.447e-01  -0.016 0.987590    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed               -3.006e-02  1.335e-01  -0.225 0.821899    
education_2catNon-Higher Education                 3.915e-02  1.196e-01   0.327 0.743436    
pp2.Household                                     -5.529e-02  1.698e-01  -0.326 0.744713    
pp3.Household                                     -1.648e-01  1.508e-01  -1.093 0.274418    
pp1.Education                                     -1.831e+00  2.793e-01  -6.555 5.90e-11 ***
pp2.Education                                     -3.604e+00  4.374e-01  -8.240  < 2e-16 ***
pp3.Education                                     -1.996e+00  2.639e-01  -7.563 4.40e-14 ***
pp1.Work                                           4.688e-01  1.800e-01   2.605 0.009206 ** 
pp2.Work                                          -1.773e-02  1.902e-01  -0.093 0.925708    
pp3.Work                                           2.202e-01  1.623e-01   1.356 0.175077    
pp1.Others                                         8.701e-01  1.473e-01   5.906 3.65e-09 ***
pp2.Others                                         1.095e-01  1.712e-01   0.640 0.522435    
pp3.Others                                        -1.402e-01  1.548e-01  -0.905 0.365392    
employment_2catNot Employed:pp2.Household         -3.642e-02  2.135e-01  -0.171 0.864535    
employment_2catNot Employed:pp3.Household         -2.906e-02  1.852e-01  -0.157 0.875334    
employment_2catNot Employed:pp1.Education         -1.645e-01  3.834e-01  -0.429 0.667972    
employment_2catNot Employed:pp2.Education          1.302e+00  4.510e-01   2.886 0.003908 ** 
employment_2catNot Employed:pp3.Education         -1.020e+00  3.946e-01  -2.586 0.009731 ** 
employment_2catNot Employed:pp1.Work              -3.480e+00  3.452e-01 -10.082  < 2e-16 ***
employment_2catNot Employed:pp2.Work              -2.188e+00  3.047e-01  -7.183 7.46e-13 ***
employment_2catNot Employed:pp3.Work              -2.439e+00  2.532e-01  -9.635  < 2e-16 ***
employment_2catNot Employed:pp1.Others            -3.551e-01  1.682e-01  -2.111 0.034761 *  
employment_2catNot Employed:pp2.Others            -1.396e-01  2.163e-01  -0.646 0.518526    
employment_2catNot Employed:pp3.Others            -2.467e-01  2.011e-01  -1.227 0.219985    
weekendWeekend:pp2.Household                       5.493e-02  2.179e-01   0.252 0.800987    
weekendWeekend:pp3.Household                      -1.112e-01  1.932e-01  -0.576 0.564955    
weekendWeekend:pp1.Education                      -1.994e+02  5.356e+06   0.000 0.999970    
weekendWeekend:pp2.Education                      -2.171e+00  6.697e-01  -3.242 0.001191 ** 
weekendWeekend:pp3.Education                      -3.289e+00  7.348e-01  -4.477 7.69e-06 ***
weekendWeekend:pp1.Work                           -2.777e+00  2.858e-01  -9.717  < 2e-16 ***
weekendWeekend:pp2.Work                           -1.732e+00  2.948e-01  -5.875 4.40e-09 ***
weekendWeekend:pp3.Work                           -2.811e+00  3.242e-01  -8.669  < 2e-16 ***
weekendWeekend:pp1.Others                         -4.862e-01  1.816e-01  -2.677 0.007437 ** 
weekendWeekend:pp2.Others                         -6.115e-01  2.316e-01  -2.641 0.008288 ** 
weekendWeekend:pp3.Others                         -5.239e-01  2.037e-01  -2.572 0.010129 *  
regionEast Germany:pp2.Household                   6.202e-02  2.183e-01   0.284 0.776363    
regionEast Germany:pp3.Household                  -6.381e-02  1.935e-01  -0.330 0.741536    
regionEast Germany:pp1.Education                  -8.322e-01  4.287e-01  -1.941 0.052272 .  
regionEast Germany:pp2.Education                  -5.512e-01  5.473e-01  -1.007 0.313879    
regionEast Germany:pp3.Education                   5.084e-01  2.894e-01   1.757 0.079036 .  
regionEast Germany:pp1.Work                        3.845e-01  2.182e-01   1.762 0.078054 .  
regionEast Germany:pp2.Work                        8.331e-02  2.359e-01   0.353 0.724014    
regionEast Germany:pp3.Work                        4.049e-01  2.059e-01   1.966 0.049280 *  
regionEast Germany:pp1.Others                     -5.503e-02  1.893e-01  -0.291 0.771266    
regionEast Germany:pp2.Others                     -5.042e-02  2.228e-01  -0.226 0.820964    
regionEast Germany:pp3.Others                      1.346e-01  1.951e-01   0.690 0.490090    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp2.Household  4.324e-02  1.952e-01   0.221 0.824749    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp3.Household  2.644e-02  1.717e-01   0.154 0.877582    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp1.Education -1.809e+00  4.911e-01  -3.684 0.000231 ***
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp2.Education -1.187e+00  6.326e-01  -1.876 0.060692 .  
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp3.Education  1.661e-02  3.527e-01   0.047 0.962438    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp1.Work       1.005e-02  2.119e-01   0.047 0.962152    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp2.Work       5.307e-02  2.188e-01   0.242 0.808403    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp3.Work       1.345e-01  1.993e-01   0.675 0.499871    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp1.Others    -8.390e-02  1.703e-01  -0.493 0.622264    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp2.Others     8.854e-02  2.113e-01   0.419 0.675187    
marital_2catdivorced/single/widowed:pp3.Others     1.865e-01  1.788e-01   1.043 0.297105    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp2.Household  -1.798e-01  1.809e-01  -0.994 0.320261    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp3.Household   4.048e-02  1.591e-01   0.254 0.799126    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp1.Education   2.450e-03  3.250e-01   0.008 0.993987    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp2.Education  -7.999e-03  4.372e-01  -0.018 0.985401    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp3.Education  -1.020e+00  3.199e-01  -3.189 0.001435 ** 
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp1.Work       -1.438e-01  1.914e-01  -0.751 0.452471    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp2.Work        2.617e-01  2.008e-01   1.303 0.192489    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp3.Work       -8.571e-02  1.776e-01  -0.482 0.629472    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp1.Others     -1.777e-01  1.566e-01  -1.135 0.256442    
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp2.Others     -5.014e-01  1.844e-01  -2.719 0.006554 ** 
education_2catNon-Higher Education:pp3.Others     -3.683e-01  1.643e-01  -2.242 0.025007 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                               edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(age)                   1.000e+00      1 0.246 0.619866    
s(hh_size)               1.000e+00      1 3.827 0.050471 .  
s(age):pp1.Household     1.170e+00      9 0.183 0.198834    
s(age):pp2.Household     3.532e+00      9 1.180 0.008329 ** 
s(age):pp3.Household     3.340e+00      9 0.892 0.031459 *  
s(age):pp1.Education     6.296e+00      9 9.825  < 2e-16 ***
s(age):pp2.Education     5.435e+00      9 6.388  < 2e-16 ***
s(age):pp3.Education     6.405e+00      9 9.911  < 2e-16 ***
s(age):pp1.Work          6.366e+00      9 3.218 9.81e-05 ***
s(age):pp2.Work          5.132e+00      9 3.395 6.15e-06 ***
s(age):pp3.Work          5.985e+00      9 2.504 0.000907 ***
s(age):pp1.Others        4.969e-05      9 0.000 0.541613    
s(age):pp2.Others        2.939e+00      9 0.825 0.022736 *  
s(age):pp3.Others        6.313e+00      9 4.565  < 2e-16 ***
s(hh_size):pp1.Household 2.562e-05      6 0.000 0.536601    
s(hh_size):pp2.Household 1.163e-05      6 0.000 0.911366    
s(hh_size):pp3.Household 1.375e-05      6 0.000 0.770463    
s(hh_size):pp1.Education 1.403e+00      6 0.559 0.060431 .  
s(hh_size):pp2.Education 1.314e+00      6 0.474 0.082245 .  
s(hh_size):pp3.Education 2.594e+00      6 2.562 0.000366 ***
s(hh_size):pp1.Work      1.349e-05      6 0.000 0.637494    
s(hh_size):pp2.Work      9.294e-06      6 0.000 0.713391    
s(hh_size):pp3.Work      8.699e-01      6 0.250 0.166660    
s(hh_size):pp1.Others    1.394e-04      6 0.000 0.365903    
s(hh_size):pp2.Others    1.310e+00      6 0.342 0.183593    
s(hh_size):pp3.Others    1.582e-01      6 0.029 0.324605    
s(token)                 3.159e+02    836 0.652  < 2e-16 ***
s(Bundesland)            3.501e-05     14 0.000 0.938054    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.224   Deviance explained = 44.2%
fREML =  12829  Scale est. = 1         n = 8316

This is the result of gam.check(), which seems to be good.
> gam.check(modGI) # all good

Method: fREML   Optimizer: perf newton
full convergence after 14 iterations.
Gradient range [-1.015485e-05,8.092237e-06]
(score 12829.3 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [2.016303e-06,68.70775].
Model rank =  1147 / 1147 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                               k'      edf k-index p-value
s(age)                   9.00e+00 1.00e+00    0.84    0.44
s(hh_size)               6.00e+00 1.00e+00    0.84    0.54
s(age):pp1.Household     9.00e+00 1.17e+00    0.84    0.41
s(age):pp2.Household     9.00e+00 3.53e+00    0.84    0.38
s(age):pp3.Household     9.00e+00 3.34e+00    0.84    0.40
s(age):pp1.Education     9.00e+00 6.30e+00    0.84    0.41
s(age):pp2.Education     9.00e+00 5.44e+00    0.84    0.41
s(age):pp3.Education     9.00e+00 6.40e+00    0.84    0.34
s(age):pp1.Work          9.00e+00 6.37e+00    0.84    0.50
s(age):pp2.Work          9.00e+00 5.13e+00    0.84    0.34
s(age):pp3.Work          9.00e+00 5.98e+00    0.84    0.40
s(age):pp1.Others        9.00e+00 4.97e-05    0.84    0.40
s(age):pp2.Others        9.00e+00 2.94e+00    0.84    0.36
s(age):pp3.Others        9.00e+00 6.31e+00    0.84    0.41
s(hh_size):pp1.Household 6.00e+00 2.56e-05    0.84    0.54
s(hh_size):pp2.Household 6.00e+00 1.16e-05    0.84    0.53
s(hh_size):pp3.Household 6.00e+00 1.38e-05    0.84    0.52
s(hh_size):pp1.Education 6.00e+00 1.40e+00    0.84    0.53
s(hh_size):pp2.Education 6.00e+00 1.31e+00    0.84    0.50
s(hh_size):pp3.Education 6.00e+00 2.59e+00    0.84    0.47
s(hh_size):pp1.Work      6.00e+00 1.35e-05    0.84    0.54
s(hh_size):pp2.Work      6.00e+00 9.29e-06    0.84    0.55
s(hh_size):pp3.Work      6.00e+00 8.70e-01    0.84    0.49
s(hh_size):pp1.Others    6.00e+00 1.39e-04    0.84    0.51
s(hh_size):pp2.Others    6.00e+00 1.31e+00    0.84    0.56
s(hh_size):pp3.Others    6.00e+00 1.58e-01    0.84    0.55
s(token)                 8.64e+02 3.16e+02      NA      NA
s(Bundesland)            1.60e+01 3.50e-05      NA      NA

This is the prediction vs the read data.

My further questions are about visualization and model check.
The plot of draw(modGI) does not show any trend. Is this because of the complexity of the model?

The second question is that some suggest using the DHARMa package to check the model. Like this.
testDispersion(modGI, plot = F)

DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via sd of residuals fitted vs. simulated

data:  simulationOutput
dispersion = 0.94755, p-value = 0.592
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = modGI, plot = F)
plot(simulationOutput, title = "modGI") 


The KS test does not good. Should I also consider the result using DHARMa package or only consider the result of gam.check()?

What is the aim of the modeling exercise? If it is to understand why people differed in their number of contacts then perhaps it is of less interest to split sample your data and instead use all of it to better estimate the smooth and parametric effects in your model (which are presumably the things of interest). If instead you want to predict, then perhaps plot sampling your data is reasonable.
Q1
This shouldn't be a choice between a model for a discrete response and a model for a continuous response. The response is one or the other, not both.
What is the response? That should guide your choice of family.
Q2
It would be cleaner to do this:
... + employment_2cat * period * place + ...

instead of what you are doing. We use interaction(f1, f2) to build the by factor because you can't do by = f1 * f2 as * is going to be interpreted as multiplication not interaction, because this term is not a formula. In the formula use the normal period * place to generate the interaction.
I also think you should do interaction(f1, f2) before you fit the model; create it in your data frame, say:
data <- data |>
  transform(pp - interaction(place, period, drop = TRUE))

before you split the data.
The NaN suggests you are fitting to complex a model presumably for the parametric term; do you have enough observations for all combinations of employment_cat2, place, and period in the training data?
It would have been useful if you'd actually showed the output from summary() here.
Q3
I'm not sure how you think anyone here can answer this - you haven't actually state what you question is in the context of the data, and haven't explained what most of the variables are, including token.
The output basically says that the variation among levels of token is statistically interesting, being a highly unusual amount of variation if there was no difference between the levels of token (the null hypothesis).
It also says that there is essentially zero variation between levels of Bundesland, whatever that is.
Q4
mgcv is telling you that your data for which you are trying to predict is not compatible with the data you used to fit the model. This usually results from one or more variables in the data used to fit the model having different factor levels to the data you are trying to predict at.
While you did set drop.unused.levels = FALSE, and base R subset() should preserve the factor levels, something is amiss. Check that the levels of all factors in data_train match those in data_test. but as I said above, it might not be the best choice to split sample your data.

Thank you very much, Prof. Simpson! I will update the post with follow-up questions.

Sorry I did not give information about the variables I have questions with beforehand. Token is the participant ID, each participant has one ID. It is taken as a random variable because each participant recorded contact information for at least two-time points. For the training dataset and test dataset, token is different and is taken as a factor variable. The two datasets can not have the same levels of token, that is why the warning message is dropped.

@Chao if you’ve done this properly (made sure factors in both datasets have the levels of the full data set) then you wouldn’t see this warning. You need to fix that problem otherwise your split sampling strategy will not work at all

Yes, after I use the full dataset, there is no warning message anymore.

That's not what I mean @Chao, you can do your split sampling if you want, just make sure that the levels on the factors are exactly the same in both the training and test sets and use drop.unused.levels = FALSE. This is the correct way to get predictions for levels not observed. But do be aware that you've just be getting 0 contribution from the random effects and this is not quite the same as integrating over the random effects if you use a nonlinear link function.

Thank you, Prof Simpson. I am reading one of your blogs on this topic. Do you have any suggestions on the straight line when using the draw() function?
